# flutter render a lot of item in a line

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a ListView with an RTL ListViewItem that contains some chips. I want to show these chips only in 1 line, the extra should be shown by ... and not show, something like below:
[image]
how can I do that?

this is my current code:

```
Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 16,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 80,
                                color: Colors.black54,
                                child: MyNetworkImage(
                                  url: item.imageUrl,
                                  height: 100,
                                  width: 80,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 8,
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(item.nurseName),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 8,
                                ),
                                Text(item.nurseType),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 8,
                                ),
                                //chips should be show here
                                )
                              
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It looks like the image is exactly what you said you want to show

Comment: yes, but I build it just to show what I want. text of chips can be larger or smaller. sometimes should show 5 chips some times 4 chips or maybe less.